# Class not detecting a member which is a Date

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to build a file to compare the working time for every worker vs their scheduled time.

I've build some classes to achieve that, but I'm having problems when giving times as keys for the dictionary classes.

Here you can see I already have a key `#2:30:00#` (item 4) and I'm giving a key `#2:30:00#` but the code wants to add it as a new one:

[image: Add key]

Once I add it:

[image: Key added]

Now I have 2 items with the same value (item 4 and item 17).

This is the code for the class:

```
Option Explicit
Private m_Tramo As Object
Property Get Tramos(ByVal Key As Date) As Tramos
    With m_Tramo
        If Not .Exists(Key) Then .Add Key, New Tramos
    End With
    Set Tramos = m_Tramo(Key)
End Property
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set m_Tramo = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
End Sub
Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set m_Tramo = Nothing
End Sub
Public Property Get Keys() As Variant
    Keys = m_Tramo.Keys
End Property
Public Property Get Count() As Long
    Count = m_Tramo.Count
End Property
```

There is more to it, but it doesn't matter here.

Now the code to add the keys for the first time:

```
Sub CalculaTramosProgramados(arr As Variant, Agentes As Buca, Horario As String, AgenteHoy As Dias)

    Dim HoraI As Date
    HoraI = Left(Horario, 5)

    Dim HoraF As Date
    HoraF = Right(Horario, 5)
    If HoraF < HoraI Then HoraF = HoraF + 1

    Dim TramoInicial As Date
    If Minute(HoraI) < 30 Then
        TramoInicial = TimeSerial(Hour(HoraI), 0, 0)
    Else
        TramoInicial = TimeSerial(Hour(HoraI), 30, 0)
    End If

    'Vamos a rellenar con 30 minutos todos los tramos
    Dim i As Long
    Dim TramoActual As Date
    For i = 0 To Application.RoundUp(DateDiff("n", HoraI, HoraF) / 30, 0) - 1
        TramoActual = TramoInicial + TimeSerial(0, 30 * i, 0)
        AgenteHoy.Tramos(TramoActual).Programado = 30
    Next i

    'Primer tramo no completo
    If Minute(HoraI) <> 0 Or Minute(HoraI) <> 30 Then
        If Minute(HoraI) < 30 Then
            AgenteHoy.Tramos(TimeSerial(Hour(HoraI), 0, 0)).Programado = 30 - Minute(HoraI)
        Else
            AgenteHoy.Tramos(TimeSerial(Hour(HoraI), 30, 0)).Programado = 60 - Minute(HoraI)
        End If
    End If

    'último tramo no completo
    If Minute(HoraF) <> 0 Or Minute(HoraF) <> 30 Then
        If Minute(HoraF) < 30 Then
            AgenteHoy.Tramos(TimeSerial(Hour(HoraF), 0, 0)).Programado = Minute(HoraF)
        Else
            AgenteHoy.Tramos(TimeSerial(Hour(HoraF), 30, 0)).Programado = Abs(30 - Minute(HoraF))
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

The parameters are an array full of data, a initialized instance for the main class(which contains this one), schedule and shortcut reference for the parent class for this one (to clean a bit the code).

This procedure fills everything up allright, but when I  come back here, then the code tries to add the new time when it already exists.

```
Sub CargarReales(arr As Variant, Agentes As Buca)

    Dim i As Long
    Dim Login As String
    Dim Centro As String
    Dim Dia As Date, Tramo As Date
    Dim CargarTramo As Boolean
    Dim AgenteHoy As Dias
    For i = 2 To UBound(arr)
        Dia = arr(i, 1)
        Centro = arr(i, 2)
        CargarTramo = compruebaTramo(Dia, Centro)
        If Not CargarTramo Then GoTo Siguiente
        Login = arr(i, 4)
        Tramo = Mid(arr(i, 3), 4, 8)
        Set AgenteHoy = Agentes.Logins(Login).Dias(Dia)
        AgenteHoy.Tramos(Tramo).Real = arr(i, 5) / 60
Siguiente:
    Next i

End Sub
```

Again, parameters are an array full of data and the main class.

I made sure that everything the code was providing to the class was the right type of variable, in this case `Date` variables holding only time, not dates.

Any clues on why is VBA doing this?

Comment: How are these items added, both in the same way?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav this: `AgenteHoy.Tramos(TramoActual).Programado = 30` adds the item for the first time. And this: `AgenteHoy.Tramos(Tramo).Real = arr(i, 5) / 60` shouldn't add anything which already existed, but it does.

Comment: Date in VBA is internally stored as Double (time as a fraction of a day). So the Keys are not the same - they look the same rounded to 1 second.

Comment: @BrakNicku giving `Strings` instead should solve my problem?

Comment: Most definitely, other solution would be to store Long number of seconds, or minutes or whatever granularity you need

Comment: @BrakNicku so.. I switched from `Date` to `String` and it's working fine now!